# Python -Uploading multiple files on GAE using Blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am using the following html form to upload two files on gae

```
<form id="insert-budget-form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate()">
        Budget Book Name:<br> <input type = "text" id = "bookName" name = "bookName" placeholder = "E.g. Budget Book 2016"/>
        <br><br>
        File:<br> <input type = "file" id = "bookFile" name = "bookFile"/>
        <br><br>
        Highlight:<br> <input type="file" id = "highlightFile" name = "highlightFile"/>
        <br><br>
        <input type="date" id="bookDate"  name="bookDate"/>
        <input type="submit" id="insert-budget-sub" value="Insert"/>
    </form>
```

I am generating upload url using ajax when the user selects the first file and using jQuery I am assigning the url as an action to form

Now, at my server side , I am getting the first file, how to obtain the second file. Here is the server side code:

```
class BudgetBookUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):

        bookName = self.request.POST.get('bookName')
        bookDatetime = self.request.POST.get('bookDate')

        dateParts = bookDatetime.split("-")

        date = datetime.date(int(dateParts[0]), int(dateParts[1]),     int(dateParts[2]))

        if bookName != "" and date:

            q = BudgetBook.query(BudgetBook.bookName == bookName)

            if q.get():
                self.redirect("/manage_budgetbook?success=dup")
            else:
                bookUpload = self.get_uploads()[0]
                highlightUpload = self.get_uploads()[1]


                budgetBook = BudgetBook(
                        bookBlobKey = bookUpload.key(),
                        highlightBlobKey = None,
                        bookName = bookName,
                        bookDate = date)

               budgetBook.put()

               self.redirect("/manage_budgetbook?success=true")
```

Is syntactically getuploads()[1] correct to use for getting the second file and storing it?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `getuploads()[0]` and `getuploads()[1]` use `getuploads('name of the form field')[0]`